# How to retrieve data from firebase database with an observable

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Setup:

```
 1. ionic: 3.20.0
 2. AngularFire2 V5.0.0-rc6
 3. Cordove: 8.0.0
 4. firebase: "^4.12.0"
```

I try to retrieve data from my database like this:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
```

Where `FirebaseListObservable` has no exported member 'FirebaseListObservable'

```
export class HomePage {
   items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

   constructor(
      public db: AngularFireDatabase
    ){

       this.items = db.list('/restaurant_menu');
       console.log('check', this.items);
    }
}
```

And in the html template:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item class="text" *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{item}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

But this returns me: `Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'`

And the console.log shows me this:

```
{query: Reference, update: ƒ, set: ƒ, push: ƒ, remove: ƒ, …}
auditTrail:ƒ (events)
push:ƒ (data)
query:Reference {repo: Repo, path: Path, queryParams_: QueryParams, orderByCalled_: false}
remove:ƒ remove(item)
set:ƒ dataOperation(item, value)
snapshotChanges:ƒ (events)
stateChanges:ƒ (events)
update:ƒ dataOperation(item, value)
valueChanges:ƒ (events)
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: console.log('check', this.items); is show something or not ???

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: ` console.log('check', this.items);` don't work with observables. You need subscribe to get the data

Comment: `this.items.subscribe(res=>console.log(res))`

Comment: @Hareesh It returns me this: TypeError: this.items.subscribe is not a function

Comment: Do `db.list('/restaurant_menu').valueChanges();`

Comment: @Hareesh Returns me an empty array

Comment: Double check the path. Remove the `/` and try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how Angularfire2 doc says

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

export class HomePage {
   itemsRef: AngularFireList<any>;
   items: Observable<any[]>;

   constructor(
      public db: AngularFireDatabase
    ){

       this.itemsRef = db.list('restaurant_menu');
       this.items = this.itemsRef.valueChanges();
       this.items.subscribe(res=> console.log(res));
    }
}
```

You can check the [doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#deleting-the-entire-list)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the observable (valuechanges) in a variable then use the async tag.

```
   items$: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase){
       this.items$ = this.db.list('/restaurant_menu').valueChanges();
    }
```

In your html

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item class="text" *ngFor="let item of (items$ |async)">
        {{item}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since RxJS 6 you can use the `from()` operator like:

```js
getUsers(): Observable<firestore.DocumentSnapshot<firestore.DocumentData>> {
    return from(this.db.collection('users').get());
}
```